# How to know in Flex when the user has completed resizing the browser window

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flex3, resize

I need to do some updates to components after a user has resized the browser window.  Is there a good solution to determine when a user has completed resizing? I wasn't able to find any flex events that would cover this case.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119389/flex-problem-with-resizeevent-resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "perfect" solution unfortunately. All you get is repeated RESIZE events. The user can stop resizing, and resume again, at any time, which is not foreseeable.

Probably the best (but not nearly perfect) solution would be to start a timer when you get a RESIZE event. When the timer fires, do what you have to do (resize complete). When you get a RESIZE event while the timer is still running, ignore the event and restart the timer.